# How to hide classes on some pages in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

How do I hide some CSS classes on some pages in WordPress?  Like if I want to hide featured image in blog posts we use:

```
.single .post-thumbnail {
    display:none;
}
```

I want the class (like `.single`) for homepage, search page, archives, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to target the page class. If you look at the source code on whatever page you are on, you'll notice the body class include a unique identifier for your page. You can then target that way. See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) for a full run-down of page classes.

Home is home, search is search, archives is archive. The homepage won't be single because that's reserved for posts.

You could set custom ones with a filter.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'new_body_class' );
function new_body_class( $classes ) {

    if ( is_front_page())
        $classes[] = 'custom-class';
        return $classes;
```

Comment: I don't understand php . Can I use it like this  ? 
.home .class-i-want-to-hide { display:none ; } , 
.search .class-i-want-to-hide { display:none ; }

Comment: Yes that is how you would target. That filter is for ADDING classes, however. It would lend for greater specificity (`is_front_page` could be exchanged for something like `is_page('search')` for instance).